# Jogar variável do js no html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Fiz dois inputs date, e quando clica em "gerar" ele mostra no console o produto que tem nessas datas, mas ele é uma variável, como faço para virar uma classe e jogar no html? aí toda vez que eu chamar a class ele aparece, ex.: 
`<h2 class="produto-1"></h2>`
Aí ele apareceria aí.
***obs.: ele pega o produto de uma api que eu fiz.***

**Código:**

```
 <body>

    <input type="date" id="inicio">
    <input type="date" id="fim">
        <button onclick="PostData();">GERAR</button>
<!-- -->


    <script>
        function PostData() {
            var inicio,fim;
            inicio = document.getElementById('inicio').value;
            fim = document.getElementById('fim').value;
                fetch('http://localhost/api', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                    body: `inicio=${inicio}&fim=${fim}`
                }).then(response => response.json().then(data => ({
                    data: data,
                    status: response.status
                })
                ).then(res => {
                    var insere = (res.data.dados.nome);
                    console.log(insere);
                })
                    )
        }

    </script>

 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça o seguinte, crie primeiro o elemento em seu html da seguinte maneira: `<h2 class="produto-1"></h2>`, abaixo do `console.log` que você deu para exibir, faça o seguinte: `$('.produto-1').html(insere)`; e veja o resultado.

Um exemplo básico:

```js
function PostData(){
   var r = $('#inicio').val();
   $('.produto-1').html(r);

}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="inicio">
    <input type="date" id="fim">
        <button onclick="PostData();">GERAR</button>
<!-- -->
<h2 class="produto-1"></h2>


    
        





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

A diferença é que você vai está pegando o conteúdo via `ajax`.